# For $f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n\ltimes SO(n))$ I do not understand this equality?

Tags: fourier-analysis, representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

Let denoted by $G = \mathbb R^n\ltimes SO(n)$ the motion group of $\mathbb R^n$, a typical element $g\in G$ is written as $g = (x, k), x \in \mathbb R^n, k\in SO(n)$. Let $f\in L^{\infty}(G)$, I would like to know why this we have the following equality

$$\int_{SO(N)}f(x,k k')\, \overline{\pi_{i,j}}(k') \, dk' \, \underbrace{=}_{??} \, \sum_{s=1}^r (f_{s, j}\otimes \pi_{s,i}) (x,k),$$
where $f_{i, j}(x)=\int_{SO(N)}f(x,k')\, \overline{\pi_{i,j}}(k') \, dk'$ and where $\pi_{i,j}$ is a matrix coefficient of an irreducible unitary representation $\pi$ of of rank $r$ of $SO(n)$.

Thank you in adavance

Comment: $x$ is not really relevant, is it?

Comment: $f_i(x)$ not $f_i$.

Comment: $(f_i\otimes \pi_{i,j}) (x,k)$ not $\pi_{i,j} (x,k)$

Comment: I edited the original post to eliminate what I thought were typos.  Please check if it is as you think it should be,  Not a good idea, by the way, to use $k$ both as a group element and an integer index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semidirect product is irrelevant since $x$ is fixed throughout, and for fixed $x$,  $k \mapsto f(x, k)$ is a bounded function on $\rm{SO}(n)$.  So the general setting is : $G$ is a compact group, $\pi: k \mapsto (\pi_{i,j}(k))$ is a not necessarily irreducble finite dimensional unitary matrix representation of $G$, and $f \in L^\infty(G)$.  Let
$$
f_{i,j} = \int_G f(k) \overline\pi_{i,j}(k)\, dk.
$$
Calculate
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_G f(k k') \overline\pi_{i,j}(k')\, dk' = 
\int_G f(k') \overline\pi_{i,j}(k^{-1} k')\, dk'  \\
&=  \int_G f(k') \sum_s \overline \pi_{i, s}(k^{-1}) \overline \pi_{s, j}(k') \, dk' = \sum_s f_{s, j}\  \overline \pi_{i, s}(k^{-1}) \\
&= \sum_s f_{s, j}\  \pi_{s, i}(k).
\end{aligned}
$$

The short summary answer: to calculate this quantity, or variants, e.g. with $k$ replaced by $k^{-1}$ or $k k'$ replaced by $k' k$, etc., you will use translation invariance on the left or right of Haar measure, and the properties of the unitary matrix representation.